# R: Function to search a text string and return dates and prices in two vectors

Tags: string, r, list, text, dataframe

I have been given the following prompt:

> Given a vector of text strings, V.text, write a function that extracts likely dollar amounts and dates from each string and returns them as separate vector components of a list of the same length as V.text.  Amounts and dates should be returned as text strings with the exact same format as the input.  For example, if one of the input strings is "Listed on 1/05/2009 for 180000 and sold for $150,250 on 3/1/2009", the output for that element should be a list containing two vectors, one for amounts and one for dates. The amounts should be "180000" and "$150,250" and the dates should be "1/05/2009" and "3/1/2009".

My attempt at a solution was:

```
four <- function(x) {

  #split the data into individual observations
  lines <- str_split(x, "\n")

  n <- length(lines)
  list.date = NA; list.price = NA; sell.price = NA; sell.date = NA; temp = NA
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    list.date[i] <- word(x[i], 3)
    list.price[i] <- word(x[i], 5)
    sell.price[i] <- word(x[i], 9)
    sell.date[i] <- word(x[i], 11)
  }
  temp <- data.frame(list.date, list.price, sell.price, sell.date)
  temp
}
```

This solution falls short for two reasons. First it outputs a data frame instead of a list containing two vectors. Secondly, if the input text string changes, my solution is useless.

I would be incredibly grateful for any support received.

Comment: where do you find the function `str_split`?

Comment: @Arun I think in `stringr` package.

Comment: @Arun yes Agstudy is correct it is in the stringr package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give an example of the previous answer idea using `gregexpr` and `regmatches` for example:

```
ll <- c("Listed on 1/05/2009 for 180000 and sold for $150,250 on 3/1/2009",
        "Listed on 1/05/2012 for $300,400  and sold 120 for on 145,25")
## extract dates
dates <- regmatches(ll,gregexpr("[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+",ll))
## remove dates 
ll <- gsub("[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+",'',ll)
## extract amounts like 120 or 120,1254 
amounts <- regmatches(ll,gregexpr("\\$?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?",ll))

 dates
[[1]]
[1] "1/05/2009" "3/1/2009" 

[[2]]
[1] "1/05/2012"

> amounts
[[1]]
[1] "180000"   "$150,250"

[[2]]
[1] "$300,400" "120"      "145,25"
```

If you want to use `stringr` package you can do the same thing using `str_extract_all`.

```
   str_extract_all(ll,"[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+")
   ll <- gsub("[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+\\/[0-9]+",'',ll)
   str_extract_all(ll,"\\$?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?")
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing a number of possible strings I think its difficult to give an answer. Here's some pointers.

Read up about regular expressions. These are pattern-matching templates which you apply to strings and get matches as results. For example, simple numbers match something like "\s[0-9]+\s" - which translates as a space character, one or more digits, then another space. If you know the numbers are going to be at least 3 digits, match on "\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]+\s". With some fiddling you can match cash amounts with dollar-signs and embedded commas.

Your dates match something like "[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+". Of course if someone throws a string with "01/Jan/2010" at you then you need a regexp to match that.

So, work out what regexps are likely to occur, match them, see how many matches you get.

`help(regexp)` in R will get you started.